# how to parse command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, parsing, getopt

I am trying to parse command line arguments in C. Currently, I am using `getopt` do the parse. I have something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   while((c=getopt(argc, argv, "abf:")) != -1)
   {
     switch(c)
     {
        case 'a':
        break;
        case 'b':
        break;
        case 'f':
        puts(optarg);
        break;
        case ':':
        puts("oops");
        break;
        case '?'
        puts("wrong command");
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

then need to use `./a.out -f`to run the program, and `-f` is the command element, but looks like `-f` must start with a `'-'`, if I do not want the command element starts with '-', i.e, using `./a.out f` instead of `./a.out -f`, how to achieve it?

if `getopt` does not support parsing a command line in this way, are there any other library to use in C?

Comment: Why don't you want flags to start with `-`? That's the UNIX convention.

Comment: Agreed.  Making your command line options "special" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Unrelated: It would likely help immensely if `c` were declared.

Comment: In fact without that, how will you tell the difference between a positional argument and a floating/optional one?

Comment: And if you do want to be a special little snowflake, Google is your friend. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: yes, I also agree, but there are some kind of 'requirement' that does not want to type '-'

Comment: Don't use `getopt` if you absolutely want to "parse" argument options which are *not* starting with a `-`. But that is a mistake! Your program should obey common conventions, and for them `getopt` and `getopt_long` are great!

Comment: why it is a mistake?

Comment: Because it breaks the usual conventions. For example, a very useful GNU convention is to accept `--help` as an option (and then to show some informative message explaining the various options). On Linux, try `ls --help` or `mv --help`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Think of tools like `apt-get` or GNU `parted`, which expect a command not starting with a hyphen as a parameter. It may make sense, to not use `-`-options. Depends on the use case, however (things like `ps` are a design mistake IMO).

Comment: These tools have sophisticated help utilities (in that sense `git` is really great). And they still accept most arguments (after the second) with an hyphen. The first argument is often a sub-command verb.

Comment: BTW, your question is really too vague. You should explain a bit what your program should do, and give some concrete example of program options.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't think we disagree, following conventions is a good thing here. I just wanted to mention valid use cases for what OP is trying to do, after four people were saying that she shouldn't (before we've known anything about the real use case).

Comment: @ratzily If your program also accepts file names after it (e.g. `myeditor file_name`) then how do you know that `f` is an option flag and not a filename (it could be ambiguous to parse, e.g. `./a.out f a b` -- is `a` associated with `f`, or is it an option on its own and thus an error as `f` does not have a given parameter)? The `-c` convention allows chaining (e.g. `ls -lh`), with `--arg` for long option flags (although some applications use `-arg`). DOS and Windows applications use '/c' to denote arguments, and some also accept `-c`.

Comment: ok, what is the usual convention for linux command? I mean I see some command for example ./a.out -f text.txt, the -f looks like a flag, can we do not use flag?

Comment: @mafso Programs like git have the syntax `git [GIT_OPTIONS] command [COMMAND_OPTIONS] -- [FILES]`, where the different options have the form `-o` or `--option` with an argument associated with some options that can be omitted in some cases. These are still following the command-line conventions.

Comment: @reece: Yes, and this is hard/impossible to parse with `getopt` and is a valid use case for OP's question (with the answer, that it's not possible with `getopt`, at least not for the `[COMMAND_OPTIONS]`).

Comment: @ratzily Typically, programs that accept files as input will specify those without any options, e.g. `gcc myapp.c`. The options can have a short name (`-f`) and/or a long name (`--force`). These options may take an argument (e.g. `--volume 50`) that may be a filename or list of filenames. The exact meaning of the options depends on the application, and should be listed via `application -h/--help`. For example, you could have `-f/--filter [FILENAME]` or `-f/--force`. The application may support reading the input file from standard input either via a `--stdin` (explicit) or if no input is given.

Comment: yes, but take git command as example, git diff -- filename, git is command name, diff is the sub command, and -- filename is the file, how could it follow linux conventions

Comment: `git` is following Linux conventions *after* its sub-command.

Comment: @mafso The `git` options cannot be parsed using the standard `getopt`/`getopt_long` API -- they use their own custom parser to handle it. It all depends on how complex you want the command-line interface to be (e.g. if you want options before the command to be handled differently to the ones after).

Comment: ok, then can we make some command like ./a.out(git) f(diff) --text.txt, using getopt?

Comment: @ratzily The `--` command line option says "anything after this is not a command-line option, but is an input to the program". In `git diff`'s case, the `--` is used to separate commit ids from paths (e.g. `git diff HEAD^ -- test.cpp`). Here, `HEAD^` is a commit id, and `test.cpp` is the path to restrict the diff output to (i.e. only show the diff of `test.cpp`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argc` and `argv` variables give you access to what you're looking for.  `argc` is "argument count" and `argv` is "argument vector" (array of strings).

`getopt` is a very useful and powerful tool, but if you must not start with a dash, you can just access the argument array directly:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv) {
    if( argc != 1) { /* problem! */ }
    char * argument = argv[1]; // a.out f ... argv[1] will be "f"
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, and `argv[1]` the first argument passed to the program.

Comment: Except that `argv[0]` is generally related to the program's name. You should rather inspect `argv[1]` when `argc>1`

Comment: are there any ways that I can use getopt without starting with '-'?

Comment: Not easily.  Getopt uses `-` to start argument lines.  I suppose you could rewrite argv to include `-` on arguments before sending them through getopt, but that would be more difficult to get correctly than manually parsing the args.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (on Linux with GNU libc) for [parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html):

- [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) with `getopt_long`; you might skip some arguments using [tricks around `optind`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt)
- [argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) which is quite powerful

and of course you could parse program arguments manually, since they are given thru `main(int argc, char**argv)` on Linux (with the guarantee that `argc>0`, that `argv[0]` is "the program name" -e.g. to find it in your `$PATH` when it contains no `/` ..., that `argv[argc]` is the `NULL` pointer, and that before that every `argv[i]` with `i<argc` and `i>0` is a zero-terminated string. See [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) for more.

[GNU coding standards: command line interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) document quite clearly some conventions. Please, obey at least the `--help` and `--version` conventions!

You might also be concerned by customizing the shell auto-completion facilities. GNU bash has [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html). `zsh` has a sophisticated [completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html).

Remember that on Posix and Linux the globbing of command words is done by the shell *before* starting your program. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `getopt` library will stop parsing at the first non-option argument. For command-based programs, this will be at the command name. You can then set `optind` to the index to start at and run `getopt` again with the command-specific arguments.

For example:

```
// general getopts
if (optind >= argc) return 0; // error -- no command
if (strcmp(argv[optind], "command") == 0)
{
    ++optind; // move over the command name
    // 'command'-specific getopts
    if (optind >= argc) return 0; // error -- no input
}
```

This should allow `git`-like command-line parsing.